# mac terminal ,hidden files using ls

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to access some files in a directory I have under applications ,

```
sudo ls applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6
```

For some reason it cannot find the folder, other folders in applications are accessible (not all of them)

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: You can't find `Adobe Flash Builder 4.6` or some directory under that you were expecting to be there? What is the output from `sudo ls ~/Applications`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces on the command line are argument separators. It looks like you want to pass four separate arguments to `ls`:

- applications/Adobe
- Flash
- Builder
- 4.6

Use quotes or escape the spaces:

```
sudo ls "applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6"

sudo ls applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote directory names that have spaces or escape the space:

```
sudo ls "applications/Adobe Flash Builder 5.6"
```

or

```
sudo ls applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 5.6
```

Finally, make sure its not `Applications`